# Subsonic ActiveRecord and SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008, subsonic3, sql-server-express

I am trying out Subsonic ActiveRecord to determine if I want to use it on any upcoming projects, and I gotta say I really like it so far. It worked great with MS SQL Server 2005 and 2008, but I am having problems with the T4 Templates and SQL Server Express. From what I can tell, Subsonic is having a problem getting the schema info from the Server Express database that I added to a test MVC app.

Does anyone have info on getting it to work with Server Server Express **(not Compact)**, and whether its even supported in Subsonic 3.0.0.4?

**EDIT:** 
This is an MVC app with MyTestDB in the App_Data folder. I have tried a number of various connection strings but nothing seems to work. The last string I have used is:

```
 <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="MyTestDBString" connectionString="server=.\SQLExpress;database=MyTestDB;integrated security=SSPI;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionstrings>
```

With the above string I am getting an SQL exception in the error list in Visual Studio saying `Cannot Open Database... The login failed`. This happens when I right click on the `.tt` files and run a custom tool.

Comment: Have you tried "integrated security=true" like in the the "Using ActiveRecord" page on the website - http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord ?

Comment: yeah, I have and a number of other combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify what database file to attach to a User SQL Server Instance. For example:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="TestVB1.Settings.Database1ConnectionString" 
          connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
          AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;
          Integrated Security=True;
          User Instance=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

See [Opening a User-Instance Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sqlexpuser_topic4) and [Building your ASP.NET MVC application with Subsonic 3.0](http://techietweaks.blogspot.com/2009/05/building-your-aspnet-mvc-application.html).

Hope it works out. Good luck!

Comment: Note...I have tried attaching the db in the past and gotten around the "login" issue. I am going to accept your answer becuase this takes care of that part of the problem problem, but I am still having problems with SubSonic and SQL Server Express. The ActiveRecord.cs class that is generated when I left click and click on custom tool is not being generated completely with SSE. Thanks for the help.